# How to get the bands to implement in Chart.js the band extension?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I have been trying to implement: https://github.com/bbc/Chart.Bands.js , in my code but I can not seem to get the bands to show. I have copied and pasted the code into my project and I can get the graphs to show but I want the bands and the color changing aspect. I am new to chart.js and javascript, as well as implementing packages off of github. Is there anyone who knows anything about this stuff? This is the chart that I am getting
[image]

This is the chart that I would like to display: 
[image]

I understand that the colors and numbers are randomized thus the data is different. What I am trying to do is get the line in the second graph to appear and the colors to change.
I have literally copied the code from this website: https://github.com/bbc/Chart.Bands.js/blob/master/samples/line.html

Comment: You should paste code when your code is broken.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know your code I can just tell you how it should be done.

https://jsbin.com/yiyejumaye/1/edit?html,js,output

```
options: {
  bands: {
    yValue: 40,
    baseColorGradientColor: [
      'rgb(255, 100, 100)'
    ],
    bandLine: {
      stroke: 2, 
      colour: 'rgba(100, 100, 255, 1)',
      type: 'solid',
    },
  }
}
```

Note that my import in the JSBin is easier but it's an older release. You shouldn't use that in your application. It's just easier for a JSBin.